# Building programmatically a project

Tags: c#, msbuild

I need to build a project programmatically for a .csproj I am creating on the fly.
While searching Google I found the classes and API provided by the MS for the MSBuild Engine. With that information, I create a process which executes msbuild.exe and then reads the output, but now I want to use the namespace `Microsoft.Build.Execution` to build the project. This is my program:

```
public class Compiler
{
   private static string locationOfMSBuilldEXE = "";
   public static void Build(string msbuildFileName)
   {
       BuildManager manager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;

       ProjectInstance projectInstance = new ProjectInstance(msbuildFileName);
       var result = manager.Build(new BuildParameters() 
                {
                    DetailedSummary = true
                }, 
                new BuildRequestData(projectInstance, new string[] { "Build" }));
       var buildResult = result.ResultsByTarget["Build"];
       var buildResultItems = buildResult.Items;

       string s = "";
   }
}
```

The results show that this is building fine, but I need to know the detailed output from the compile and how to view it. It would be really helpful if someone can give me link to a good tutorial or a book on MSBuild.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a instance of a class that implements the `ILogger` interface to  your `BuildParameters`. You can add a new instance of one of the supplied loggers in the `Microsft.Build.Logging` namespace, or you can implement `ILogger` yourself as it is very small and there is a helper class in the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities` namespace called `Logger` that is easy to extend.

[Build loggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.logging.aspx)

[ILogger interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger.aspx)

[Logger helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.logger.aspx)

Comment: thankx.. can you also tell my where to find a good tutorial for the same set of namespaces?

Comment: @Parv - Other than the documentation (which I think is excellent), you can try this one http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-Build-Engine-Pro-Developer/dp/0735626286

Comment: There are only two books devoted to MSBuild that I'm aware of, and both are good (and reviewed by the developers): (1) The MSPress book mentioned above -- but the link is to the first edition, get the second edition, which includes 4.0 features; (2) MSBuild tips and tricks - search on Amazon - this is very much an advanced guide. The MSDN documentation is quite limited, I'm afraid.

Comment: @cheerless - I've had good results with the documentation with creating custom tasks, hooking the build process, etc...

Comment: All links are broken :-(

Answer (score 15):

Thanks @ritchmelton. Though I figured it out myself.
Here is my code : I have used an in built logger `ConsoleLogger`

```
public class Compiler
    {
        private static string locationOfMSBuilldEXE = "";
        public static void Build(string msbuildFileName)
        {
            ConsoleLogger logger = new ConsoleLogger(LoggerVerbosity.Normal);
            BuildManager manager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;

            ProjectInstance projectInstance = new ProjectInstance(msbuildFileName);
            var result = manager.Build(
                new BuildParameters() 
                {
                    DetailedSummary = true,
                    Loggers = new List<ILogger>(){logger}
                }, 
                new BuildRequestData(projectInstance, new string[] { "Build" }));
            var buildResult = result.ResultsByTarget["Build"];
            var buildResultItems = buildResult.Items;

            string s = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to build a project or solution, without elaborate parameters, you can do it more simply. Pseudocode:

```
using namespace Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

var p = Project.Load("path to project");
p.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Release");
p.Build(...);
```

That's it! BuildParameters and so forth are for quite advanced scenarios. Visual Studio itself uses them.

Dan (msbuild dev)

Comment: Awesome! Please note that the syntax has changed in MSBuild 14. Its `new Project("path to project")`.

Comment: Is it possible to publish a web application with this?