# Building a .sln in C# executable

Tags: c#, msbuild, microsoft.build

I'm trying to build a .sln in C#. I have the following code.

```
try
{
  Console.WriteLine("Building Solution...\n");
  string projectFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\Solution.sln";
  ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
  Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
  GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");

  BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

  BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), BuidlRequest);

catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.Write("Error:" + e.Message);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Completed Solution build...\nPress any key to continue...");
```

It doesn't thow a error, it does show `Completed Solution build...` but I can't find the executable in `\bin\Release`. Am I forgetting something or how can I check it?

Comment: Does your solution define an `x86` platform?  By default, Visual C# projects usually just define `Any CPU`.

Comment: You could be explicit: `GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyOutput");`

Comment: `Any CPU` and `GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\Solution\\bin\\Release");` didn't make any difference.

Comment: It is like, it's not building anything...

Comment: Then you might need to add a logger and check the actual output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942499/building-programatically-a-project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get it working, solution is not building to due errors in the code. Anyway this is the solution.

```
string projectFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\Solution.sln";
ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\\bin\\Release");

BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
bp.Loggers = new[] {
  new FileLogger
  {
    Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed,
    ShowSummary = true,
    SkipProjectStartedText = true
  }
};

BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BeginBuild(bp);

BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

BuildSubmission BuildSubmission = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.PendBuildRequest(BuildRequest);
BuildSubmission.Execute();
BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.EndBuild();
if (BuildSubmission.BuildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure)
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: As I thought! Glad you managed to track the issue down and if all else fails... Log! :-)

Comment: Hi Alex, do you happen to know how I can change parameters in individual projects? I can change the AssemblyName using the globalProperty but it would overwrite every project in the sln.