# Always got BuildResultCode.Failure from Microsoft.Build library

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Recently I used [Microsoft.Build package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/) with VS2017 for building C# project programmatically. However, I always got `BuildResultCode.Failure`. Cannot figure out why, need help, thanks.
Here's my code:

```
string projectFileName = @"C:\Downloads\ToBeBuilt\ToBeBuilt\ToBeBuilt.csproj";

ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
pc.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Debug");
pc.SetGlobalProperty("Platform", "x86");
pc.SetGlobalProperty("OutDir", @"C:\Downloads\Artifacts");

Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
globalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
globalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");
globalProperty.Add("OutDir", @"C:\Downloads\Artifacts");

BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, globalProperty, "15.0", new string[] { "Build" }, null);
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), BuidlRequest);
BuildResultCode a = buildResult.OverallResult;
```

And here is the target project to be built:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  ...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="Build">  
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>    
  </Target> 
</Project>
```

Comment: Check the `buildResult.Exception` property. What is it?

Comment: If possible, please check following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802603/building-a-sln-in-c-sharp-executable/27807830#27807830

Comment: @Alex thanks for the help! How should I mark the answer? Actually, there're multiple causes leading to the failure of build. I followed the post you gave and kept debugging with the log file MSBuild provided, I finally made it.

Comment: Since there are multiple possible causes to the failure, you should provide the detailed exception message to help the investigation, otherwise the question can not be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Always got BuildResultCode.Failure from Microsoft.Build library

You can check the similar issue to kept debugging with the log file MSBuild provided:

```
string projectFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\Solution.sln";
ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");
GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\build\\\bin\\Release");

BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
bp.Loggers = new[] {
  new FileLogger
  {
    Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed,
    ShowSummary = true,
    SkipProjectStartedText = true
  }
};

BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BeginBuild(bp);

BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

BuildSubmission BuildSubmission = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.PendBuildRequest(BuildRequest);
BuildSubmission.Execute();
BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.EndBuild();
if (BuildSubmission.BuildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure)
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

Certify:[Building a .sln in C# executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802603/building-a-sln-in-c-sharp-executable/27807830#27807830)