# Build single project only with MSBuild BuildManager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following code which suppose to compile a project in my solution. The compilation is successful but my problem is that other projects in the solution are also compiled and I want to avoid this.

```
public static void msBuild(Project p) {
    var pc = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();
    Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        {"Configuration", "Debug" },
        {"Platform", "AnyCPU" },
    };
    //TODO: MSBuild is compiling some other projects besides the one specified.
    BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(
        p.paths.project, //this is path to project's .csproj file
        GlobalProperty,
        null,
        new string[] { "Build" },
        null
    );
    var bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
    bp.Loggers = new ILogger[] {
        new MSBuildLogger(){
            Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed,
        }
    };
    bp.DetailedSummary = true;
    log($"********Compiling {p} project with MSBuild***********");
    BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.ResetCaches();
    var br = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
        bp, BuidlRequest);
    logBuffer();
    log("Compilation result:", br.OverallResult);
    if (br.Exception != null) throw br.Exception;
}
```

This are some basic, modified examples from the internet. I can't say I understand how this suppose to work. I've tried to read logs but is't even hard to tell when a new projects is about to compile.
I know that this compiles other projects from the time it takes + when I produce some error in other project I can see it.

I would like to get the same behavior as I do when clicking **Build** on project in **Solution Explorer** (I have build unchecked for all projects in configurations manager)

Comment: Does the  `p.paths.project` means the full path of the project file? Or you define the class paths? You can try to use the Class `ProjectInstance`, like `ProjectInstance projectInstance = new ProjectInstance(msbuildFileName);`, check the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942499/building-programmatically-a-project

Comment: I've just tried that. The result is the same - the builder complies 40 project's in solution. Strange thing is that for some other project I build with this methods, the builder works as I expect (compile single project)

Comment: It seems more related to your projects, have you checked what is special about those projects? It works fine on my side. Could you test the new blank project with this method, check if you still have this issue.